# Invalid anonymous type member declarator c# linq?

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have this json structure :

```
[
  {
    "code": "T01",
    "stock": 0
  },
  {
    "code": "T02",
    "stock": 1
  }
]
```

How can I achieve his structure :

```
[{ 
 T01: {
     stock: 0
 }
}, {
  T02: {
     stock: 1
 }
}]
```

using linq in C#.

Currently I have this line of code :

```
var inv = inventory.Select(i => new { code = i.SiteCode, stock = i.Stock).ToList().ToArray();
```

The value of inv will get the first structure result.

I am trying to do something like this :

```
inv = inventory.Select(i => new {  i.SiteCode = new { stock = i.Stock} }).ToList().ToArray();
```

I am getting the following compile error :

> Error 1   Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type
>   members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or
>   member access.

Any Help ?

Comment: `new {  i.SiteCode = ...` - if you want to declare the member name dynamically, you cannot do it like this.

Comment: BTW - why use both `ToList()` and `ToArray()`? if the output you want is an array just use `ToArray()`

Comment: ok, I removed it.

Comment: The first `var inv=` line is broken, it doesn't contain the end `}` for one thing.

Comment: You can't create an anonymous type with dynamic property names. Why not simply deserialize into a `JObject` or similar that is dynamic in nature?

Comment: You could generate a parsed string like the second one, but it will never be a valid json.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create property names dynamically like that with linq. You must give a specific name. If what you want to achieve is like you described then better convert it to a dictionary. Something like this:

```
var inv = inventory.ToDictionary(key => key.SiteCode, value => new { Stock = value.Stock});
```

In the case that you might have duplicate `SiteCode`s then maybe for the `value` you can use a collection or otherwise use `ToLookup`.

---

About the usage of the `ToArray`/`ToList` - most of linq's methods are differed executed and are more like instructions on what to do (queries). When adding a method like `ToList`/`ToArray`/`FirstOrDefault`/`Sum`... - only at that point the query is actually executed and returns the result. in the case above you use `.ToList().ToArray()` - the linq is executed and returned for the `List` and then you convert it into an array. Use only one of the two according to the output you want (or as my suggestion above convert to a dictionary or lookup

Comment: this soultion is no working, it is saying the name value and key does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user123456 - sorry, had a typo after value it was `=` instead of `=>`. Fixed

Comment: Actuaqlly, it produced this json  [{
  "Key" : "AM1",
  "Value" : {
    "stock" : 1
    }
  }]  I still do not want the key and values

Comment: I did this   var dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (var inv in inventory)
                {
                   var val = new { stock = inv.Stock};
                   if(dic.ContainsKey(inv.SiteCode))
                   {
                     continue;
                   }
                   dic.Add(inv.SiteCode, val);
                } This got me what I want.

Comment: @user123456 - good one for a non-linq :) a bit of CR - do a `if(!....) { did.Add... }` instead of the `continue`. And if using linq you can use a `Where` and then `Select`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that, because even though the type is anonymous, it is still a static type (not a dynamic one) and it must be known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

For this structure (I have made a class to represent yours):

```
class A
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public int stock { get; set; }
}
```

I have made the following algorithm, not so nice but gives a kind of what are you asking:

```
var objects = new List<A> { new A { code = "T01", stock = 1 }, new A { code = "T02", stock = 2 } };
string s = "[";
objects.ForEach(x => s += "{" + x.code + ": {stock: " + x.stock + "}},");
s = s.Remove(s.Length - 1, 1);
s += "]";
```

You can complete the  formatting by adding blank spaces where you need, but again, what are you looking for is not a valid json format.